# Trouble solving a Cauchy's problem, what went wrong?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, cauchy-problem

I am trying to solve the following Cauchy's problem:

$$u_x-3u_y=\sin x + \cos y \\ u(t,t)=p(t) $$

Following the example given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMYKW.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewJk.png).

I guess the system of equations associated with it is:

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}=\frac{dz}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}$$

I tried to solve the diferential equations in the following manner

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-3\implies y = -3x + c_1$$

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dz}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=\sin(x)+\cos(y)\implies z= -\cos(x)+\cos(y)x + c_2$$

But it does not work. And I noticed in the pages I referenced before that the coordinate $z$ appears somewhere, but it does not appear in my solution. I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Have another look at your very last implication. Where did $z$ go??? And don't forget that $y$ depends on $x$!

Comment: @HansLundmark Ah, yes. Thanks. But even switching $y$ for $z$, it seems the solution is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, since $y$ depends on $x$. The integral of $\cos(y)$ is not $\cos(y) x$. Write $dz/dx = \sin(x)+\cos(-3x+c_1)$ first, and *then* integrate with respect to $x$. That will tell you the value of $u(x,y)$ (expressed as a function of $x$) along the line $y=-3x+c_1$.

Answer (score 1):

The key is already given by Hans Lundmark in comment. The aim of my answer below is to show how to properly apply the boundary condition.
$$u_x-3u_y=\sin(x)+\cos(y)$$
Your calculus is correct up to
$$y+3x=c_1$$
For the second characteristic equation :
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\sin(x)+\cos(y)\implies u+\cos(x)-\int \cos(y)dx = c_2$$
$$u+\cos(x)-\int \cos(c_1-3x)dx = c_2$$
$$u+\cos(x)+\frac13\sin(c_1-3x) = c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u+\cos(x)+\frac13\sin\big((y+3x)-3x\big) = F(y+3x)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{u=-\cos(x)-\frac13\sin(y) + F(y+3x)}$$
Condition :
$$p(t)=u(t,t)=-\cos(t)-\frac13\sin(t) + F(4t)$$
With $4t=X\quad\implies\quad t=\frac{X}{4}$
$$F(X)=p(\frac{X}{4})+\cos(\frac{X}{4})+\frac13\sin(\frac{X}{4})$$
The function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=y+3x$ :
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-\cos(x)-\frac13\sin(y) +p(\frac{y+3x}{4})+ \cos(\frac{y+3x}{4})+\frac13\sin(\frac{y+3x}{4})}$$