# Trouble computing $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}=\frac{dz}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKQku.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9EDe.png).

Suppose we have the following partial differential equation:

$$u_x-3u_y=\sin x + \cos y $$

I write the system of differential equations:

$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}=\frac{dz}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}$$

How do I apply that stuff in the text in this example? There is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74skf.png) example in the book but in this case, we were lucky things worked fairly easy and we could write $\frac{d(x+z)}{x+z}=\frac{dy}{y}$. I don't see how that could be done in this case.

Comment: Try looking at the first equality for starters: what relation does it imply for $x$ and $y$? This will allow you to express $y$ in terms of $x$ and thus reduces the problem to a separable DE.

Comment: @Semiclassical This implies $dy/dx=-3$, right? Do I integrate this one first and substitute in the remaining equation?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you do. Solving the ODE you wrote down with integration constant $C_{1}$ and substituting it into the equalities above, you can replace $y$ to get $$\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{du}{\sin(x) + \cos(C_{1} - 3x)}$$ (or you can replace $x$ instead) which is easily solvable.

Comment: For context, you should perhaps mention your previous question about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292768/trouble-solving-a-cauchys-problem-what-went-wrong#comment8939446_4292768

Answer (score 2):

You could also apply the proportionality trick:
$$
ds=\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}
\implies ds = \frac{\sin x\,dx-\frac13\cos y\,dy}{\sin x + \cos y}
$$
so that with the third fraction immediately
$$
du =\sin x\,dx-\frac13\cos y\,dy
\\
u=-\cos x-\frac13\sin y+c_2
$$
follows

Answer (score 1):

$$u_x-3u_y=\sin(x)+\cos(y)$$
The charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}=\frac{du}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{-3}$ :

$$y+3x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{du}{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}$ :
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\sin(x)+\cos(y)\implies u+\cos(x)-\int \cos(y)dx = c_2$$
$$u+\cos(x)-\int \cos(c_1-3x)dx = c_2$$
$$u+\cos(x)+\frac13\sin(c_1-3x) = c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u+\cos(x)+\frac13\sin\big((y+3x)-3x\big) = F(y+3x)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=-\cos(x)-\frac13\sin(y) + F(y+3x)}$$
The PDE has an infinity of solutions since they are an infinity of arbitrary functions $F$ until no boundary condition is specified in the wording of the question.

The function $F$ might be determined if a valid boundary condition was given.